# How to provide HttpClient to StaticInjector - Angular 5?

Tags: angular, angular5, ng-bootstrap

I am trying dynamically create a component using the NgbModal from the ng-bootstrap library (which I believe uses the ComponentFactoryResolver method underneath) but am running into an issue when I try to provide HttpClient into the Static Injector.

Has anyone run into this issue and know what to do? Thanks in advance for the help!

EDIT: The code where I create the new component.

```
let modal: NgbModalRef =
        this.modalService.open(HoursApprovalModalComponent, {
            injector: Injector.create( [
                {provide: FormBuilder, useClass: FormBuilder, deps: []},
                { provide: AttendanceService, useClass: AttendanceService, deps: [HttpClient]},
                { provide: HttpClient, useClass: HttpClient, deps: []},
                // { provide: HttpHandler, useClass: HttpHandler, deps: [] },
            ] ),
            size: 'lg'
        });
```

Comment: Are you talking about actually talking about [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples)? What exactly are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "dynamically generated component"? Have you looked at the example showing how to use a component as the modal body?

Comment: I'm trying to make use of the HttpClient service inside of the component I generate with ng-bootstrap (just noticed I misspelled that, my bad). I can get the component to show up inside of the modal but my issue comes up when I pass an injector into the NgbModalOptions. Whenever I try to use the HttpClient instance inside the new component, I get an error that states can not read property 'handle' of undefined. 'handle' comes from the HttpHandler inside of HttpClient so I was wondering how to get that to be created correctly. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Why would you need to pass an injector to the component? Just inject HttpClient (or, preferrably, a service using HttpClient) in the component constructor, as you would with any other component.

Comment: I think that's what I was doing, unless there's a way to inject services individually. I'll edit in more of the code where I create the component so you can see what's going on.

Comment: See http://plnkr.co/edit/upVW6GLrcPJF0xgVWoTH?p=preview for a demo.

Comment: So I was unneccessarily passing in an injector:P If you wouldn't mind answering, could you name a use case for the Injector class from the Angular library? And thanks so much for the help!

Comment: AFAIK, you would need to pass an injector when the modal needs to use the same injector as the component opening the modal, for example, because the component has its own providers, or is lazy-loaded. If the service and components that the modal component uses are part of the root module, you don't need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `HttpClient` is available in the root module, you don't need to pass any injector. That's useful if you want the component to use an injector different from the root one. Just inject HttpClient in your modal component as you would do in any other component.

Here's a [working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/upVW6GLrcPJF0xgVWoTH?p=preview)

Comment: plunker is broken... stuck on loading

Comment: Works fine here.

Comment: (SystemJS) XHR error (404) loading https://unpkg.com/rxjs@%5E5.5.2/operators/switchMap
 Error: XHR error (404) loading https://unpkg.com/rxjs@%5E5.5.2/operators/switchMap
     at o (https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.47/dist/system.js:4:17461)
     at XMLHttpRequest.W.i.onreadystatechange (https://unpkg.com/systemjs@0.19.47/dist/system.js:4:18049)
     at XMLHttpRequest.wrapFn [as __zone_symbol___onreadystatechange] (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.8.10/dist/zone.js:1032:39)
     at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (https://unpkg.com/zone.js@0.8.10/dist/zone.js:414:31)